# How to get the top of an image minus 100 pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the to target the top of an image minus 100px.
I'm using the below which isn't working but I think it shows what I'm trying to do... Any help is appreciated

```
const target = document.querySelector('#myTarget').offset().top - 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see this link [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)